# All configration for gridelements only in files

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements

I want to include all configration for gridelements in files.
So, when I store my CE Backend Layout in back-end it works correctly

```
mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts {
  exampleKey {
    title = Example
    icon = EXT:my_ext/Gridelements/Teaser/Resources/Public/Icons/icon.gif
    config {
      backend_layout {
        colCount = 1
        rowCount = 1
        rows {
          1 {
            columns {
              1 {
                name = Content
                colPos = 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I set configuration in TSConfig, content not rendering.

```
tx_gridelements {
  overruleRecords = 1
  setup {
    2-Teaser {
      title = Teaser
      description = Teaser
      icon = EXT:my_ext/Gridelements/Teaser/Resources/Public/Icons/icon.gif
      topLevelLayout = 0
      config {
        colCount = 1
        rowCount = 1
        rows {
          1 {
            columns {
              1 {
                name = Content
                colPos = 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gridelements find this template, but there is no rendering content

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
  1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  1 {
    cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    cObject.file = EXT:my_ext/Gridelements/Teaser/Resources/Private/Templates/Template.html
  }
}
```

Comment: http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2017/04/07/typo3-8-7-x-gridelements-typoscript-tca-und-templates-auslagern-1985/

Comment: do you pay attention to the loading order? Your Settings must be loaded after the Gridelements.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit late, but I've got the same problem with `gridelements`and `TYPO3 8.7 LTS` - especially with the configuration in files, like you.
I have copied the SourceCode from `CE BackendLayouts` in my filesystem, that was my fault. Here's the right code:

PageTS

```
tx_gridelements {

    setup {

      SectionColoured {

        title = LLL:EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Language/...
        description = LLL:EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Language/...

        # optional #icon = EXT:yourext/Resources/Public/Images/...

        # optional # flexformDS = FILE:EXT:yourext/Configuration/FlexForms/Gridelements/SectionColoured.xml

        config {

            colCount = 1
            rowCount = 1
            rows {
              1 {
                columns {
                  1 {
                    name = LLL:EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Language/...
                    colPos = 101
                  }
                }
              }
            }

        }

      } 
   }
}
```

TS

```
// loaded ts after install the ext:gridelements
[userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('gridelements')]
    <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:gridelements/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts" extensions="ts">
[global]

tt_content.gridelements_pi1 =< lib.contentElement
    tt_content.gridelements_pi1 {
    templateName = Generic
    variables {
        content =< tt_content.gridelements_view
    }
}

tt_content {
    gridelements_pi1 = COA
    gridelements_pi1 {
        20 {
            10 {
                setup {
                    SectionColoured < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
                    SectionColoured {
                        cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
                        cObject {
                            file = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Extensions/Gridelements/SectionColoured.html
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tt_content.gridelements_view < tt_content.gridelements_pi1
```

And the gridelement-template-file at: `EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Extensions/Gridelements/SectionColoured.html`

```
<section class="main-content {data.flexform_colour}">
    <article>
        <f:format.raw>{data.tx_gridelements_view_columns.101}</f:format.raw>
    </article>
</section>
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Since your backend layout is not ***1*** but ***2-Teaser***, your TypoScript setup must match that identifier:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
  2-Teaser < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  2-Teaser {
    cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    cObject.file = EXT:my_ext/Gridelements/Teaser/Resources/Private/Templates/Template.html
  }
}
```